# How do we determine if a subgroup of $S_n$ is normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Ok, so I have $H = \{ e,(12),(34),(12)(34) \}$ being a subgroup of $S_4$.
How do I prove that it is also normal (or isn't)? Because I don't really want to check every case, and there must be a more elegant way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be a good idea to calculate conjugacy classes first; then see if a subgroup is a union of those or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements in $S_n$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle structure. In particular, $(12)$ and $(13)$ are conjugate, so since $(13) \not \in H$ then $H$ is not a normal subgroup of $S_4$.

$S_4$ does have a normal subgroup isomorphic to $H$, but it is generated by the permutations having cycle structure as follows: $(\cdot \cdot) (\cdot \cdot)$.

Comment: Wait, why do they have to have the same cycle structure in order to be conjugate?

Comment: It is a standard theorem. You can find a proof [here](http://www.math.wm.edu/~vinroot/415conj.pdf)

Comment: Or, well, you can see it explicitly. $(123)(12)(132) = (23) \not\in H$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any two elements with the same cycle structure are conjugate.  Thus, your subgroup $H$ is not inner automorphism invariant, and so not normal.  For instance, $(12)(34)$ and $(13)(24)$ are conjugate.